# How to call TabActivity getTabHost() from another activity? to avoid NullPointerException

Tags: android, tabs

Im in a process of learning android.
Want to implement tabbed browsing functionality; For this purpose I have following activity

```
public class CustomList extends ListActivity {
....

and inside this (and other activities I want to put the tabs)

for example:
Resources res = getResources();

   **TabActivity ta = new TabActivity();**
        TabHost host = **ta.getTabHost();**  // this line returns **NullPointerException**

        host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("first")
                .setIndicator("First")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, First.class)));
These lines are included inside OnCreate().
```

Probably it would be better to have separate activity with tab definitions and just call it in every other activities. But, Im not sure how to do this.

Please for suggestion to solve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to have multiple activity within a single tab.

In order to do this, you have to first create an Activity which extend TabActivity, and initialize its tabs with activities extending TabGroupActivity.

```
public class BaseActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  addTab("home",home_tab,tab_sales_icons,new Intent(this, TabGroupSalesActivity_.class));
  }
}

public class TabGroupSalesActivity extends TabGroupActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //Start the first Activity of the group
  Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, Sales_.class);
  newIntent.putExtra("XMLObject",xml);
  startChildActivity(newIntent);
  }
}
```

Here is a link with more informations on [how to have multiple activities in a TabActivity](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

Comment: wow, that's actually good. What I want to do is implement tabbed browsing. The issue is the I already use extends ListActivity in my  activity and now I can not use extends TabActivity. I am looking for a way how to add tabs not extending TabActivity; That's why I tried to create a new instance of it, TabActivity ta = new TabActivity(); and call getTabHost(); And this line now   TabHost host=ta.getTabHost(); return NUllPointException.